# Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS: Can't set omit_response_on_success for batch requests

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-batch-request

It seems for batch requests,  all the parameters are escaped as parts of relative_url, if omit_response_on_success is set to @(false), app will crash with this message: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @(false), @"omit_response_on_success", nil];

FBRequest *request1 = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:self.graphPath
                                          parameters:parameters
                                          HTTPMethod:nil];

[newConnection addRequest:request1 completionHandler:handler batchEntryName:@"entryName"];
```

If the graphPath is set to `@"me/home?omit_response_on_success=0"`, these will be no output from this operation. Any ideas?

Comment: Is 3.0 the version of the Facebook SDK or the iOS SDK?

Comment: it's the facebook SDK 3.0, which is released today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this option is currently not supported by the SDK as-is, be sure to file a feature request on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs for this.

Answer (score 0):

That should not be a parameter but a key-value in the JSON body of the request, as noted in the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). I believe the question is rather how to set that key-value in the iOS SDK since we don't have access to the body of the request. From what I could tell there is no way to do it, but I'm not sure if it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's very annoying that Facebook doesn't allow us to set this flag using the iOS SDK.  I spent hours trying to figure out a way and this is a little hack I came up with.  It should be relatively safe.  Just use the RSFBRequestConnection instead of FBRequestConnection:

```
@interface RSFBRequestConnection : FBRequestConnection

@end

@implementation RSFBRequestConnection

- (NSMutableURLRequest *)urlRequest
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super urlRequest];

    NSData *body = request.HTTPBody;
    NSString *bodyStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", bodyStr);

    NSString *fixed = [bodyStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"relative_url\"" withString:@"\"omit_response_on_success\":false,\"relative_url\""];

    request.HTTPBody = [fixed dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return request;
}

@end
```